# Octopress-rake deploy-Git remote origin not being removed

Tags: git, repository, octopress

Hello I have an octopress blog and recently just deleted my files on my computer- I have cloned my files onto my computer.
unfortunately when I try to `rake deploy` it states it give me
`fatal:'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

So I though that was strange and decided to try `git remote`
providing me with `origin`
I go even more odd? so I decided to set the url or remove and re-add the remote origin.

To reset the url I used `git remote set-url origin "my url"` and then tried to deploy again,
then the same error occured
`fatal:'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository`
so I decided to remove it, `git remote rm origin`
nothing happens and by this point i get fustrated, i check if it the remote is still there and it is ......anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: need to tell us what deployment you are using (GitHub pages?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using GitHub Pages for deployment?  You have to tell us, as each _deploy folder is setup differently.

For GitHub Pages, do note that you have two branches in your repo:

```
master # your forward facing site
source # the source that builds it
```

I know, weird huh?

What you need to know is that the `./_deploy/` folder is on MASTER.

```
~$ git branch
  master
* source
~$ cd _deploy/
deploy/$ git branch
* master
  source
deploy/$
```

So with this, there are two different sets of remotes and urls.  One set for your root folder, which is on `source` branch.  And another set of urls in `_deploy`, on your `master` branch.

Make sure you setup the remotes in this _deploy folder.

I ran into lots of issues recently with Windows, Posh-Git and Octopress with GitHub pages and had to debug line by line what Ruby was doing - when I have never seen Ruby before.  I documented the step-by-step here:

http://eduncan911.com/software/octopress-powershell-and-posh-git-oh-my.html